# Spread multiple edges by a specified scaled distance (Mathematica 10)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there way to spread multiple edges by a specified scaled distance for Graph function in Mathematica 10, something similar to MultiedgeStyle in GraphPlot for example, I would like to write:

```
Graph[edges, VertexLabel->"Name", MultiedgeStyle->0.5]
```

The Graph function doesn't support MultiedgeStyle (don't know why), is there a reason or an alternative other than using GraphPlot?

Thanks for your help!